# What kind of window crank is this, and what brand is it?

Tags: windows

[image]

Looking for a possible identity of the brand of this window handle. The issue with the handle is that while it can open, it cannot close the window, and the gears from the outside have to be pushed in order to have it close. Below is an image of the actual mechanism:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logo on thew crank handle is [Milgard](https://www.milgard.com/form/beautiful-design-brochure-3?source=google&medium=ppc&campaign=National_US_Brand_Search_Mirror&atid=7&gclid=CjwKCAiAksvTBRBFEiwADSBZfIre1YyekAETRFLT7GfeQdgXxO6bv1yRXMepLJEnoCCXeLUiU32F4xoCwZkQAvD_BwE&utm_expid=.ULoHN1txSKuknun3MUBaYg.1&utm_referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F).

You may be able to get a rep out there and perhaps they will replace it for free. Sometimes the lifetime guarantee is transferable if you are not the original owner